# Css ignoring everything after the first class

Tags: .net, css, concatenation, minify

I'm using [this guide](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Httpcombine.aspx) to create a HTTPHandler that combines script and css files to deliver them as one request each.

Basically it reads a bunch of .css files into a byte array and then response.writes the bytes to the client with a content-type of text/css(or text/javascript)

When using FireBug it appears that the CSS comes through fine...it is all there.  However, the browser itself will is only rendering CSS that is in the first file used in the combining action.

Example:

File1.css:
body { font-size: 20px; }
h1 { color: red; }

File2.css:
div { border: solid 1px black; }

All the CSS is visible via Firebug in the CSS tab...however the class from File2.css is not actually applied to divs on the page.  If I flip the order of the files, divs get a border, but nothing from File1.css gets applied.

Javascript files work totally fine, but the CSS has me totally stumped!

*EDIT TO SHOW CSS COPIED OUT OF FIREBUG*

```
body {
font-size:22px;
}
h1 {
color:Red;
text-decoration:underline;
}
div {
border:1px solid black;
}
```

*HERE IT IS FROM THE NET TAB, THE ACTUAL RESPONSE GENERATED*

```
ParamsHeadersPostPutResponseCacheHTML
Response Headersview source
Server  ASP.NET Development Server/9.0.0.0
Date    Mon, 29 Nov 2010 01:10:26 GMT
X-AspNet-Version    2.0.50727
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Cache-Control   public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=259200
Expires Thu, 02 Dec 2010 01:10:26 GMT
Content-Type    text/css
Connection  Close
Request Headersview source
Host    localhost:49598
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12
Accept  text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
Referer http://localhost:49598/



body 
{
    font-size: 22px;

}

h1 
{
    color: Red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}div 
{
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

New development.  If I create the .css files in notepad everything works fine.  Does VS2008 add something unseen to the file when creating a Stylesheet file?

*FIDDLER TEXTVIEW* (Dunno where the extra characters came from.  Interesting.

```
9a


body 
{
    font-size: 22px;

}

h1 
{
    color: Red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}div 
{
    border: solid 1px black;
}
0
```

Comment: can you post the actual css received by Firebug?

Comment: body {
font-size:22px;
}
h1 {
color:Red;
text-decoration:underline;
}
div {
border:1px solid black;
}

Comment: please edit your question and post the received CSS using code blocks so we can see it properly formatted

Comment: Please show us the raw CSS response from Firebug's Net tab.  (Although if you see all of it in the CSS tab, that proves that there aren't any syntax errors, so I'm not sure what's wrong.)

Comment: Does it work in Chrome or Safari?

Comment: Tried IE, Chrome, Safari as well...same result.

Comment: Can you try capturing it using Fiddler?  I wonder if Firebug is doing some error-rectifying whereas Fiddler will show you the raw output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `GetFileBytes` change the following lines

```
    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(physicalPath);
    // TODO: Convert unicode files to specified encoding. For now, assuming
    // files are either ASCII or UTF8
    return bytes;
```

To

```
    string content = File.ReadAllText(physicalPath, encoding);
    return encoding.GetBytes(content);
```

Comment: Worked beautifully.  I would still like to track down why Microsoft seems to be putting some non UTF8 characters in stylesheets generated via VS2008, but this will do for now. Thanks.  Any idea if the extra overhead in reading the text and then converting to bytes will be noticeable?

Comment: The overhead is a factor of the length of the file, but I'd say that it would not be noticeable. Assuming you're using the cache mechanism defined in the guide you've mentioned then the overhead is only incurred when the cache is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's wrong; if Firebug's CSS tab sees the CSS, it ought to render.

Try clearing the cache (Ctrl+F5) and restarting Firefox.

Try adding a newline between the CSS files on the server; there's a slight possibility that that might help.

Comment: That's what I thought too.  Tried these suggestions to no avail.  This is truly strange.  Worse yet, I've done this before with seemingly identical code with no problems.  Thanks for taking a look though!

Comment: I'm stumped.  If you can show me a (non-)working demo, I can investigate further.

Comment: I don't really have a way to get it up to a public site easily at the moment.  I'll leave a comment if/when I do and/or don't get it solved.

Comment: @Rco: I thought not.  Good luck.